# entity framework - how can I implement this SQL in the abbreviated EF linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

Can anyone help out with what the C# code would be to implement this SQL as Entity Framework Linq in the abbreviated form?  (e.g. where you have the "." notation such as xxx.where(... etc)

```
SELECT PN.Name, Sum(U.Amount)
FROM Usages as U, ProcessNames as PN
WHERE PN.Id == U.ProcessNameId 
   AND U.Datetime BETWEEN '2010-01-08' AND '2010-10-11'
Group By PN.Name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method-Based Query:**

To implement this in lambda we need to leverage [**Queryable.GroupJoin**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534805.aspx):

```
var query = context.ProcessNames
    .GroupJoin(context.Usages
                      .Where(u => u.Datetime >= new DateTime(2010, 1, 8) ) 
                                  && u.Datetime <= new DateTime(2010, 10, 11),
               pn  => pn.Id,
               u => u.ProcessNameId, 
               (pn, usages) => new { Name = pn.Name, 
                                     Sum = usages.Sum(u => u.Amount) });
```

**Query Expression:**

And the very same query in query expression syntax:

```
var query = 
    from pn in context.ProcessNames
    join u in context.Usages
                     .Where(u => u.Datetime >= new DateTime(2010, 1, 8) ) 
                                 && u.Datetime <= new DateTime(2010, 10, 11),
    on pn.Id 
    equals u.ProcessNameId 
    into g                      
    select new { Name = pn.Name, 
                 Sum = g.Sum(u => u.Amount) };
```

**Check the Generated SQL:** 

To verify that these queries give you your desired Sql command at runtime you can do this:

```
string sqlCommand = ((ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

**More Examples:**

For some good examples on GroupJoin, please take a look at these:

**[*Method-Based Query Syntax Examples: Join Operators*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896339.aspx)**

**[*Query Expression Syntax Examples: Join Operators*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266.aspx)**

Comment: SQL `betweens` are inclusive, so your datetime range checks need correcting to match.

Comment: excellent thanks - which approach do you think is easier to understand program in our of curiosity?  method based or query based?

Comment: You are very welcome. I Personally like the Method-Based syntax better, although Query Expression syntax is more readable and of course easier to write, but it's yet another level of abstraction and I think if we make ourselves familiar with Method Based syntax, we can always turn it into Query Expression but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I don't have your code so I'm getting no compiler help):

```
from u in context.Usages
join pn in context.ProcessNames on pn.Id equals u.ProcessNameId
where u.Datetime >= new DateTime(2010, 1, 8) && u.Datetime <= new DateTime(2010, 10, 11)
group pn by pn.Name into g
select new { Name = pn.Name , sum = g.Sum(u => u.Amount) };
```

That is the query expression version of it. To get the lambda based syntax (as I believe you are asking for this question), put the query into [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and run it.  Then click on the lambda tab in LinqPad and it will show you that syntax of the above query as if you had written it with lambda expressions (i.e., where you have the "." notation) and not a query expression.

Comment: SQL `betweens` are inclusive, so your datetime range checks need correcting to match.

Comment: @Will - Fixed the inclusions.